# GitHub 2FA Wormhole

Tags: github, ssh, authentication

I don't know if anyone has any suggestions but I am in a bind!

I've lost access to my GitHub account via switching phone numbers and having 2FA enabled.

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get denied, but I've provided GitHub with essentially everything I can, which are all my public SSH keys, password, correct email, a keychain on my Mac saying that I've logged in. I've made the mistake not getting recovery codes and I don't have access to the old phone. My past 1.3 years work of code is on GitHub for my company and I don't store any of my code on hardware as fear of theft,  I know that's also a mistake, but it's a fear of mine.

It looks like I'm out of options according to GitHub, which is why I've came to StackOverflow. Are there any workarounds, I know EVERYTHING about the account, my credit card is on file.

The only thing I can think of is showing up to the offices with my ID and credit card on file. As my profile picture is me.

Any suggestions are appreciated. I have the public SSH keys, and a public key generated for one of my organizations, and still couldn't get 2FA disabled.

Comment: Contact GitHub support and let us know what they recommend

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a  workaround, especially for private repos, considering that "[Recovering your account if you lost your 2FA credentials](https://help.github.com/articles/recovering-your-account-if-you-lost-your-2fa-credentials/)" states:

> **If you've lost access to your account after enabling two-factor authentication, GitHub can't help you gain access again**.
>   Having access to your [recovery codes](https://help.github.com/articles/downloading-your-two-factor-authentication-recovery-codes) in a secure place, or establishing a secondary mobile phone number for recovery, will get you back into your account.

So if the Git repos are cloned anywhere in your company, you might get them back. But not from GitHub itself.